# Incorrect output of cyrillic symblos to QTableView from Sqlite3 database

Tags: qt, character-encoding, sqlite

I have sqlite3 database filled with symbols in cyrillic encoding. But I can't output correctly this symbols to table. So, in qt app I get something like

`�˫�� ⮢`

I tried to use different variants of codecs.

```
...            
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(codec);
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
...
```

but it doesn't take any effect on values in the table.
When I execute query in command-line sqlite application, it's allright - all value displays correctly in command line.

But how can I assign codec to QTableView fileds in qt application?

Answer (score -1):

Try using cp1251 or cp866 encoding instead of utf-8.